# In R, how to select a year-specific datum from multiple year columns?

Tags: r

I have a dataset in which for each column, I want to select a response datum based only the year of that observation.  My version of the dataset has only the first four columns; I want to create the fifth column using R syntax.  In that fifth column, yr.response, I would like only the datum that corresponds to the correct year.  I'm considering some iteration if ifelse() statements (e.g. if year==2000, then select from column y2000 etc), but can't get it to work. I should add that the actual dataset has about thirty years and 19K rows, so I want to be able to automate.

```
year<-c(2000,2000,2001,2002)
y2000<-c(65,43,42,74)
y2001<-c(98,93,987,948)
y2002<-c(875,983,776,736)
yr.response<-c(65,43,987,736)
x<-data.frame(cbind(year, y2000,y2001,y2002,yr.response))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my.df <- data.frame(year, y2000, y2001, y2002)
rownames(my.df) <- as.character(rownames(my.df))
my.df$yr.respnose <- my.df[cbind(rownames(my.df), paste0("y", my.df$year))]
```

Comment: Neat solution. I did not know you could select elements from a data frame with a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a switch statement and a for loop:

```
# Define a function to return which column the year refers to
col_finder <- function(r1) {
  switch(r1,
         "2000"=1,
         "2001"=2,
         "2002"=3) 
}

# Initiallize a new column
x$yr.response2 <- NA

# Switch statements are not vectorized, so run this in a for loop
for(i in 1:nrow(x)) {
  cmn <- col_finder(as.character(x[i, "year"]))
  x[i, "yr.response2"] <- x[i, cmn]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
year<-c(2000,2000,2001,2002)
y2000<-c(65,43,42,74)
y2001<-c(98,93,987,948)
y2002<-c(875,983,776,736)
yr.response<-NA
x<-data.frame(cbind(year, y2000,y2001,y2002,yr.response))

for(year in x[,"year"]){
  x$yr.response[which(x$year==year)] <- x[which(x$year==year),grep(year,colnames(x))]
}
```

Gives:

```
> x
  year y2000 y2001 y2002 yr.response
1 2000    65    98   875          65
2 2000    43    93   983          43
3 2001    42   987   776         987
4 2002    74   948   736         736
```

I am still unsure as to what the 98 means in the y2001 column where the year is listed as 2000, but this code reproduces your example yr.response column.

This example assumes you have unique columns. In other words, you could not have two y2000 columns.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution using `Map` function and so no need for R `for loop`. 
`myrow<-as.list(df$year)` # convert the year into list for feeding into `Map`

```
myout1<-Map(function(x) df[df$year==as.numeric(x),paste0("y",x)], myrow)# use to generate the output
```

#Convert it to dataframe

```
myout2<-do.call(rbind,myout1)
```

#A small trick is needed here if we have more than one observation for each year under year column (here two observation at max for each year)

```
myout2[which(!(myout2[,1]==myout2[,2])[1]==TRUE),2]<-myout2[which(!(myout2[,1]==myout2[,2])[1]==TRUE),1]

df$yr.response<-myout2[,2]


> df
  year y2000 y2001 y2002 yr.response
1 2000    65    98   875          65
2 2000    43    93   983          43
3 2001    42   987   776         987
4 2002    74   948   736         736
```